Eigenvectors of the product of a diagonal matrix and a symmetric matrix
We say that a set of vectors $\{\phi_k\}_{1 \leq k\leq n}$ is $A$-orthogonal if $\phi_i^T A \phi_j = 0$ whenever $i \neq j$. I am trying to prove the following result:
Let $M$ be an invertible diagonal matrix and $K$ a symmetric matrix, both of the same dimensions. Show that the set of eigenvectors of $M^{-1}K$ are $M$-orthogonal and $K$-orthogonal.
I am not even sure if this result is true, but I tried several examples in Matlab, and it seems to be always the case. I also don't know if it is necessary to assume that all eigenvalues have multiplicity $1$.

Careful. Not every diagonal matrix is invertible.

Fixed, thank you.

What was the purpose of the last edit? I don't like it

No. $MK\neq KM$ in general, even if $K$ is symmetric and $M$ is diagonal.

What if $(MK) = (KM)^T$? I think this may be the case.

It is explained in the first line.

The set ${v_i}$ is $M$-orthogonal if and only if it is $K$ orthogonal:
Suppose $v_i$ is an eigenvector of $M^{-1}K$ that corresponds to the eigenvalue $\lambda_{i}$, $i=1,\dots,m$. Since $M$ is diagonal, it is symmetric. And since it is invertible, $(M^{-1})^T=(M^T)^{-1}=M^{-1}$. We have
$$v_i^T K v_j=(M^{-1}M v_i)^T K v_j=(M v_i)^T M^{-1}K v_j=\lambda_{j}(M v_i)^T v_j=\lambda_{j} v_j^T M v_i.$$

First, the eigenvalues have to be distinct. Otherwise $M = K = I$, $v = e_1$, $w = e_1 + e_2$ gives a counterexample, for both are eigenvectors, but their inner product is $1$, not zero.
If you want to say "repeated eigenvalues, but orthogonal eigenvectors", then maybe it's true...but I wouldn't bet on it.
But let's say that there's a full complement of distinct eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $M^{-1}K$.
Suppose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are distinct eigenvalues of $M^{-1} K$, with eigenvectors $v$ and $w$ respectively. Then, remembering that $K^t = K$ and $M^t = M$ when necessary, we can check the $M$-orthogonality of eigenvectors.
\begin{align}
(M^{-1}K) v &= \alpha v  \tag{1}\\
Kv &= \alpha Mv         \tag{2} \\
Mv &= \frac{1}{\alpha} Kv \tag{3} \\
v^t M^t &= v^t M =  \frac{1}{\alpha} v^t K \tag{4}\\
Kw &= \beta Mw \tag{5}
\end{align}
Now let's look at $v^t M w$:
\begin{align}
v^tMw 
&= \frac{1}{\alpha} v^t Kw & \text{by 5}\\
&= \frac{\beta}{\alpha} v^t Mw &\text{by 6}
\end{align}
so $(1 - \frac{\beta}{\alpha}) v^t Mw = 0$. Because $\alpha \ne \beta$, this tells us that $v^t M w = 0$ as required.

And replacing $M$ instead of $K$ after (5) gives $v^t\frac{1}{\beta}Kw = \frac{1}{\alpha}v^tKw$, and this implies that $\left(\frac{1}{\beta} - \frac{1}{\alpha}\right)v^tKw = 0$, implying the $K$-orthogonality.
